# Order to call registered events

Tags: api, events, frameworks

I'm building a framework which relies heavily on user-registered events,

All I really wanted to ask, was; is there an accepted order for calling event callbacks? i.e. should they be called in the order they were registered, or in reverse-registered order? Or should I let users specify a priority?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd offer both - i.e.:

```
registerCallback(handler);
```

*and*

```
registerCallback(handler, priority);
```

That way, users of your API can specifiy the priority if it's important to them.

If the priority is not specified, then *order-of-registration* is probably the expected callback order.